# Open shell locations with c#

Tags: c#, exec, windows-shell

The code listed here does not open the file history in C#:

```
Process.Start("::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}");
```

Where is the problem? It says the path was not found.

Running the following with Windows "Run" opens the files history correctly:

```
shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}
```

Comment: With Windows 8 it works for me

Comment: For me it doesn't work with CLSID but it's OK with names (History, in your case).

Comment: Have you tried running as Administrator?

Comment: yes the same problem as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems here. The target platform and the command.

> With Windows 8 it works for me

It only works on Windows 8 because it's a new feature in Windows 8. Previous versions don't have anything mapped to that GUID.

eg if you try using something which is supported in previous versions like the classic 'god mode':

```
shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

works fine,

```
shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}
```

will give you an error message.

Secondly, you're leaving out the `shell:::` prefix when you call `Process.Start()`. It should look like:

```
Process.Start("shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}");
```

Comment: that's related to SysWow64 Directory; the program search it before system32 because the system is 64 bit